# Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "opera", $.browser is undefined ¿Como actualizar esta propiedad?

Tags: php, jquery

El error es al subir la imagen se queda cargando y en la consola me sale este error Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "opera", $.browser is undefined, como puedo actualizar esta propiedad?, he estado haciendo lo que dice aquí [https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bph2H.png) pero me sige el error, también he puesto `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>` y me funciona en localhost pero en un hosting sigue el mismo error, eso funciona en localhost.

**Datos**
PHP 7.3
jQuery v3.5.1

**Linea del error**

```
if ($.browser.opera) document.getElementById(frameId).onload = uploadCallback;
```

**Captura**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
ajaxFileUpload: function(s) {
        s = jQuery.extend({}, jQuery.ajaxSettings, s);
        var id = new Date().getTime();
        var form = jQuery.createUploadForm(id, s.fileElementId);
        var io = jQuery.createUploadIframe(id, s.secureuri);
        var frameId = 'jUploadFrame' + id;
        var formId = 'jUploadForm' + id;
        if (s.global && !jQuery.active++) jQuery.event.trigger('ajaxStart');
        var requestDone = false;
        var xml = {}     
        if (s.global) jQuery.event.trigger('ajaxSend', [xml, s]);
        var uploadCallback = function(isTimeout) {
            var io = document.getElementById(frameId);
            try{
                if (io.contentWindow) {
                    xml.responseText = io.contentWindow.document.body ? io.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML : null;
                    xml.responseXML = io.contentWindow.document.XMLDocument?io.contentWindow.document.XMLDocument:io.contentWindow.document;
                }
                else if (io.contentDocument) {
                    xml.responseText = io.contentDocument.document.body?io.contentDocument.document.body.innerHTML:null;
                    xml.responseXML = io.contentDocument.document.XMLDocument?io.contentDocument.document.XMLDocument:io.contentDocument.document;
                }
            } catch(e) { jQuery.handleError(s, xml, null, e); }
            if (xml || isTimeout == 'timeout') {
                requestDone = true;
                var status;
                try {
                    status = isTimeout != 'timeout' ? 'success' : 'error';
                    if (status != 'error') {
                        var data = jQuery.uploadHttpData(xml, s.dataType);  
                        if (s.success) s.success(data, status);
                        if (s.global) jQuery.event.trigger('ajaxSuccess', [xml, s]);
                    }
                    else jQuery.handleError(s, xml, status);
                } catch(e)  { status = 'error'; jQuery.handleError(s, xml, status, e); }
                if (s.global) jQuery.event.trigger('ajaxComplete', [xml, s]);
                if (s.global && !--jQuery.active) jQuery.event.trigger('ajaxStop');
                if (s.complete) s.complete(xml, status);
                jQuery(io).unbind();
                setTimeout(function() { try { $(io).remove(); $(form).remove(); } catch(e) { jQuery.handleError(s, xml, null, e); } }, 100);
                xml = null;
            }
        }
        if (s.timeout > 0) setTimeout(function(){ if(!requestDone) uploadCallback('timeout'); }, s.timeout);
        try{
            var form = $('#'+formId);
            $(form).attr({ action: s.url, method: 'post', target: frameId });
            if(form.encoding) form.encoding = 'multipart/form-data';
            else form.enctype = 'multipart/form-data';
            $(form).submit();
        } catch(e) { jQuery.handleError(s, xml, null, e); }
        if ($.browser.opera) document.getElementById(frameId).onload = uploadCallback;
        else {
            if (window.attachEvent) document.getElementById(frameId).attachEvent('onload', uploadCallback);
            else document.getElementById(frameId).addEventListener('load', uploadCallback, false);
        }
        return {abort: function () {}}; 
    },
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa "da error"? ¿Podrías poner el mensaje de error que obtienes? Por favor, no uses imágenes cuando puedes copiar y pegar el código

Comment: Hola Pablo, he intentado poner la función entera pero no me dejaba, el error es al subir la imagen se queda cargando y en la consola me sale ese error, que esta obsoleto esa propiedad. Ya he podido poner la función entera. Gracias por contestar.

Comment: Este es ele error Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "opera", $.browser is undefined

Comment: El $.browser no funciona en versiones superiores a la 1.9 de jQuery. En la documentación indica que funciona si incluyes el complemento jQuery migrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás mezclando jQuery y el uso de Javascript *vanilla*, lo que te está complicando la vida. Este trozo de código:

```
if ($.browser.opera) document.getElementById(frameId).onload = uploadCallback;
else {
  if (window.attachEvent) 
    document.getElementById(frameId).attachEvent('onload', uploadCallback);
  else 
    document.getElementById(frameId).addEventListener('load', uploadCallback, false);
}
```

lo podrías reescribir así:

```
$('#'+frameId).on('load', uploadCallback);
```

dejando que el propio jQuery se encargue de detectar internamente cómo tu navegador gestiona los eventos.

Comment: Muchas gracias a los 2, solucionado.